# CSS: background color for <li> troubles (with floated <img>)

Tags: css

When the `<li>`'s have a background color and are floating up against an image that is floated left.

I would like the background color of the li to be left justified to the paragraph, not to the left edge of the page. Any bulletproof ways of doing this? I wish it was as simple as adding a `display: inline;` to the `<ul>`. A large left margin that is wider than the image is not an option, as the images will be varying widths.

Thanks for your input. This one has been an ongoing struggle in my designs, and I would like to figure out a perfect "fix" for this.

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3KHKY/3/

/// css ---->

```
li { background-color: red; margin-left: 10px; color: white;}
img { float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
```

/// html --->

```
<p>
  <img src="http://i.ehow.com/images/a04/v1/cb/started-new-kitten-200X200.jpg" />
</p>
<h2>Title</h2>
<ul>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
<p>More content here.</p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you: "the background color of the li to be left justified to the paragraph, not to the left edge of the page". How can a color be justified, which paragraph do you mean, and what is currently justified to the left edge of the page? It's all justified to the right edge of the kitten IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/lex_rwx/QFKeY/)?

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is inherent in floating layouts. Floating merely pushes the internal contents of other elements to one side: in most cases it does not move the elements themselves (though clearly it can cause them to resize).

As Lex suggests, inline-block is the answer. This causes the element to act in the same way as an image, i.e. to reign in its box and keep that shape no matter what.

Comment: Yes, `float` is so evil... `inline-block` forever :D